# AngularJs directives - Need to get attribute value in templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to get append directive attribute value to templateUrl.
I tried several options however, templateUrl does not support `$observe` in it.
Therefore I tried below and tried to get `"devicePath"` value to `templateUrl`.
Nothing worked.
Here is my example.

```
<me-direct  device-path="{{contentUrl}}"  tmp-url="{{appTemplateUrl}}"></me-direct>
```

**Directive js file**

```
angular.module('meDevices').directive('medirect',medirect);

    function medirect(){
        return{
            scope:{
              devicePath:'@'

            },
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'directCtrl',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // some ode
                attrs.$observe('devicePath', function(value){
                    console.log(value);
                    scope.url =  value;
                    console.log(scope.url);
                });


            },
            templateUrl: scope.url
        }
    }
```

Anyhow, this is not working since `scope.url` is not accessible from `templateUrl`. Any thoughts??

EDIT

But If I send attribute as this everything will work.

```
<me-direct  device-path="some/common/url/to/view.html"  tmp-url="{{appTemplateUrl}}"></me-direct>
```

Comment: what is this `templateUrl: scope.url`?

Comment: I tried to assign scope.url value to templateUrl.

Comment: where is templateUrl used?

Comment: can you find it in isolated scope?

Comment: templateUrl is a directive attribute which is use to assign the template path.

Comment: @jitendravarshney could you please explain??

Comment: templateUrl is a standard attribute dude.

Comment: standard attribute of *what*? because in your example it's on directive definition object, which doesn't support any such properties

Comment: ya Maximus saying ryt

Answer (score 0):

Try this:::

```
angular.module('meDevices').directive('medirect',medirect);

    function medirect(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
               base: '@baseUrl' 
            },
            templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
               return "http://example.com/"+attrs['device-path']+attrs['tmp-url'];
            }
        }
    }
```

Uses:

```
 <me-direct  device-path="{{contentUrl}}" tmp-url="{{appTemplateUrl}}"></me-direct>
```

Comment: can you please check those variable in UI contentUrl and appTemplateUrl...it should work...

Comment: what is baseUrl ??

Comment: its just scope param but we can not use scope binding variable in template modification...is this working for you now

Comment: have checked varaible has value or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133342/discussion-between-pankaj-badukale-and-mad).